# How to create pmml from sklearn model that can be import to python file with sklearn-pmml-model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pmml

I want to create PMML file from scikit-learn model. The pmml file will be read/import from other python files. But the results give me various errors

List of errors:

- PMML model ensemble should use majority vote.
- Sklearn only supports binary tree models.

Now i am confused which one is producing the errors. Is it when creating pmml file (export) or import pmml file? Or any other libraries recommendation that fix my problem?

I've tried many library such as sklearn2pmml, nyoka & scikit2pmml to create PMML file but the result is same.

For import pmml file, i'm using sklearn-pmml-model.

Create Model:

```
#create model and export pmml files
import pandas
iris_df = pandas.read_csv("/smart_apps/iris2.csv")

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline

pipeline = PMMLPipeline([("classifier", DecisionTreeClassifier())])
pipeline.fit(iris_df[iris_df.columns.difference(["species"])], iris_df["species"])

from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml
sklearn2pmml(pipeline, "model4.pmml", with_repr = True)

#import pmml
from sklearn_pmml_model.tree import PMMLTreeClassifier
model = PMMLTreeClassifier(pmml='/home/zeppelin/model4.pmml')
```

Expected result: Succesfully import pmml file

Comment: Why do you need PMML at all? You're training and deploying models in Python, so consider using the standard pickling technique for moving model objects around.

Comment: I just want to compare PMML and Pickle. Which do you think is better when used in production scale? PMML or pickle?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PyPMML to import pmml file in Python, for example:

```
from pypmml import Model

model = Model.fromFile('/home/zeppelin/model4.pmml')
result = model.predict(iris_df)
```